# How to fix unpickling stack underflow error when a pickled object is sent as a paramter to a GET request?

Tags: python, django, get, django-views, pickle

I am pickling my model objects and sending them as parameters to a get request, so that the objects can be used in another view.
After receiving the pickled object as string I encode it and then unpickle which gives me:

```
Exception Type: UnpicklingError
Exception Value: unpickling stack underflow
```

I want to filter the models , pickle them , send them as url parameters encode them and unpickle.
(is it because GET request encodes URLs?)

## Views.py

```
class SearchView(View):

def get(self,request):
    qs = report.objects.all()

            #FILTER STUFF

    item = pickle.dumps(qs)



    return render(self.request,self.template_name,{'qs':qs,'item':item})



def report_download(request,item):
    succ1 = item.encode()
    succ = pickle.loads(succ1)
    #DO STUFF


    return response
```

## urls.py

```
url_patterns =[ url(r'^download/( 
              ?P<item>.*)/$',views.report_download,name='dload'),]
```

## template.html

```
<form action=".">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="{%url 
    'auto_project:dload' item %}">Download</a></button>  
</form>
```